# How can I print multiple queries at once, resulting in 1 table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've tried the UNION statement, but that prints out only the first query and skips the rest. How can I print multiple queries in 1 table? With or without using the UNION statement..

```
SELECT DISTINCT
[5028account]
FROM 
XXX
WHERE
StresstestaccountEnabled LIKE '%Yes%' AND BalancesheetAmount <> 0
AND
PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [5028account]) > 0 OR [5028account] IS NULL

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
[1001account] 
FROM 
XXX
WHERE
StresstestaccountEnabled LIKE '%Yes%' AND BalancesheetAmount <> 0
AND
PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', [1001account]) > 0 OR [1001account] IS NULL


UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
[BalanceSheetType]
FROM
XXX
WHERE
StressTestAccountEnabled LIKE '%Yes%' AND BalanceSheetAmount <> 0
AND
[BalanceSheetType] NOT LIKE '%Assets%'
AND
BalanceSheetType NOT LIKE '%Liabilities%'

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT 
CorepRRR
FROM 
XXX
WHERE 
StressTestAccountEnabled LIKE '%Yes%' AND BalanceSheetAmount<>0
AND
CorepRRR NOT LIKE '%D%'
AND
CorepRRR NOT LIKE '%R%'
AND
CorepRRR NOT LIKE '%P%'
AND
CorepRRR NOT LIKE '%Not Applicable%'
```

Comment: check if each sql have something, run each separate and see. and then check

Comment: Why the mysqli tag? This appears to be SQL Server code, and there's no PHP in sight either. Make sure you tag your question accurately to get it seen by the right people. You can read the tag definitions as you add them

Comment: Can you post some sample data and expected results to support your queries?

Comment: Your code does not print only the results of the 1st query and skips the rest. Maybe you think it does so because the name of the only column in the results is `[5028account]`, but this is the way `UNION` works: if you don't give an alias for the columns, the names from the 1st query are used.

Answer (score 1):

to print all data from all the queries!!!!!1:

```
 union all
```